# Deleting a question specific to a small set of machines

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Ok, I have a question I asked about a problem I'm having in a small network of machines, but not other networks, or that other people can't reproduce.

Some people are suggesting I delete the question, the question referenced here is this one:

- [Simple C# Array throwing OutOfMemory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481937/simple-c-sharp-array-throwing-outofmemory-exception)

Just because it doesn't work on their machines, or my home machine, it remains a real problem, that I'm hoping someone might have an answer to. Also, the fact it was limited to just the network I was on at the time, was helpful to a certain extent in its own right.

What's your thoughts on deleting the question? Should I delete it and forget I had a problem, or should I delete it and start a new one? How would I phrase the new one? Should I just leave the current one open?

The code originally had a typo, that has been fixed (if anyone reads the comments).

Comment: Before I delete it, or try to phrase a new question, or keep editing it with additional info/research, I just wanted to know what the best/recommended policy was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the problem is "specific to a small set of machines" means it's actually a question about those machines. The current question+answers already clearly indicate it's going to be about the hardware or software-config of some of your PCs.

There is absolutely no value in this question for any future googler interested in arrays and OOM exceptions.

Since you're the only one with access to those faulty machines you should really research this further, and maybe come back with (an entirely different and therefore new) question involving

- exact code (those typos were inexcusable)
- compilation details (commandline preferred)
- details about the Fx versions, for the working and non-working cases
- details about hardware and OS versions
- etc

Comment: thanks Henk, will do, sorry about the original typo's, I posted the first bit of code and tried to copy the example from machine to machine, the machine I am using to do development is has no external internet connection.

Answer (score 6):

If you think the current question mis-represents the problem, you should delete it.  If you think the current question accurately states the problem, but just needs more time for someone to answer it, you can leave it.  If you have new information later, you can amend your question, and it will get more views.